# MYSQL Join column but return NULL on not existent row

Tags: mysql, join

I need a bit of help because I cannot figure it out.

I have two tables

**Table Recipes
Columns :**

```
ID, Recipe_name, Instructions
```

**Table Translations
Columns :**

```
ID, RecipeID, Translation, Country_ID
```

What I try to achieve is when a user looks up a food recipe and the user wants to have it in its own language (France or whatever) MYSQL will left (or right) join the Translated text. AND IF there are **NO TRANSLATED** text found it should return **NULL**

I tried this:

```
SELECT Recipes.* , Translations.Translation FROM Recipes
INNER JOIN Translations.Translation
ON Recipes.ID = Translations.RecipeID
WHERE Recipes.ID = 999 AND COALESCE(Translations.Country_ID, '') != '13'
Limit 1
```

`Recipes.ID = 999 <-` is a recipe stored in dbase
`Translations.Translation = 13 <-` country Id, in this case France

The above statement returns as it seems a random translated text back, I only need 13 (France) and if there is NO translated text, I want it to return NULL.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT -- With Tables:

```
**Table Recipes

    |ID |  Recipe_name | Instructions
    ----+--------------+-------------
    | 1 | Tasty Dish   | 1 spoon of sugar
    | 2 | Chicken      | 1 chicken

    ** Table Translations

    |ID |  Recipe_ID | Translation         | Country_ID
    ----+------------+---------------------+-----------
    | 1 |      1     | 1 cuillère de sucre |     13  (france)
    | 2 |      1     | 1 Lepel Suiker      |     11  (dutch)
```

Another scenario in which there are NO french translation:

```
**Table Recipes

    |ID |  Recipe_name | Instructions
    ----+--------------+-------------
    | 1 | Tasty Dish   | 1 spoon of sugar
    | 2 | Chicken      | 1 chicken

    ** Table Translations

    |ID |  Recipe_ID | Translation         | Country_ID
    ----+------------+---------------------+-----------
    | 2 |      1     | 1 Lepel Suiker      |     11  (dutch)
```

The MYSQL should still add the column TRANSLATION but filled with NULL

Comment: Use an outer join if you want to return the rows without match.

Comment: @shree.pat18 Mysql doesnt support outer join directly..

Comment: @almasshaikh Not sure I follow you. Left and Right joins are outer joins right? Perhaps I should have been more specific...

Comment: I want translation to be NULL if no translation is found, and not returning just any translation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query seems a bit confused. You say you want to use an outer join (left or right), but you use an inner join. Just use an outer join instead, and the query is simply:

```
select r.* , t.translation 
from recipes r
left join translations t on t.recipeid = r.id and t.country_id = 13
where r.id = 999;
```

Comment: This will NOT add the Translation column with NULL if no translation is found. IN fact if there are NO translations it will return NO rows at all

Comment: How do you get that idea? You get *all* recipes with id 999. Plus a Translation for country_id 13 if available. This is what an outer join does.

Comment: Yes you are correct, I missed LEFT JOIN and still used my INNER JOIN. Yours works! Much appreciated ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try left join.

```
SELECT Recipes.* , Translations.Translation FROM Recipes
LEFT JOIN Translations
ON Recipes.ID = Translations.RecipeID AND COALESCE(Translations.Translation, '') != '13'
WHERE Recipes.ID = 999 
Limit 1
```

Comment: This return also other translations, seems a random return.

Comment: Can you just give some example with values of your table.So it will be more easy.